# jQuery: IE specific issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the following but it doesn't work. I'm doing something wrong that's for sure.

```
 $.keyNav();
  $.whenPressed('t',function(){
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
  $.whenPressed('p',function(){
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").not(".category-photographie").fadeTo(200, 0.1);
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").filter(".category-photographie").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
        $.whenPressed('d',function(){
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").not(".category-design").fadeTo(200, 0.1);
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").filter(".category-design").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
        $.whenPressed('v',function(){
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").not(".category-video").fadeTo(200, 0.1);
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").filter(".category-video").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
        $.whenPressed('w',function(){
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").not(".tweet").fadeTo(200, 0.1);
   $("#grid-wrapper article.post").filter(".tweet").fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
});
```

If I removed the last `});` it works but not in IE so maybe my syntax is wrong?

I use the keynav plugin:

https://github.com/BrianTheCoder/jquery-keyboard-navigation/blob/master/README

Comment: You sure there's not an error occurring elsewhere? The IE status bar showing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your IE issue it, it doesn't seem like your posted code would cause any issues...most likely there's an error *before* this code, like a trailing comma something IE won't tolerate).  Check the developer console for errors in IE (in IE8+) and the status bar in earlier versions to see what's happening.

I do have a suggestion though, use an object map to cut down on your code here, since you're repeating yourself a lot...by doing so you can more possible syntax errors as well, like this:

```
var map = { t:"*", 
            p:".category-photographie", 
            d:".category-design", 
            v:".category-video", 
            w:".tweet" };
$.keyNav();
$.each(map, function(key, selector) {
  $.whenPressed(key,function(){
    $("#grid-wrapper article.post").not(selector).fadeTo(200, 0.1)
                             .end().filter(selector).fadeTo(200, 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I'm no programmor so I did my best ;-) In IE8 I'm in the console and click on Start Debugging the page on the left reloads but nothing appear on the right.